# pymongo returning "Command raised an exception: InvalidDocument: cannot encode object:" when storing data

Tags: python, mongodb, discord.py, pymongo

I have a question, how to use Pymongo to write a store of roles and other items, I tried to do this:

```
@Bot.event
async def on_ready():
    await Bot.change_presence(status = discord.Status.online, activity = discord.Streaming(name = '!help', url = ''))
    print(Bot.user.name + " is ready.")

    for guild in Bot.guilds:
        for member in guild.members:
            post = {
                "_id": member.id,
                "server_id": guild.id,
                "balance": 300,
                "xp": 0,
                "lvl": 1
         },
         {
             "role": 0,
             "cost": 0
         }

         if collection.count_documents({"_id": member.id}) == 0:
             collection.insert_one(post)
```

And

```
    @commands.command()
    async def add_shop(self, ctx, role: discord.Role, cost: int):
        self.collection.update_one({"_id": ctx.author.id},
            {"$set": {"role": role}})
        self.collection.update_one({"_id": ctx.author.id},
            {"$set": {"cost": cost}})

    await ctx.message.add_reaction("✅")

@commands.command()
async def shop(self, ctx):
    r = self.collection.find_one({"_id": ctx.author.id}["role"])
    c = self.collection.find_one({"_id": ctx.author.id}["cost"])

    await ctx.send(r, c)
```

But it didn't work out for me. I decided to contact you. Thank you in advance!

Comment: When you say "it didn't work out", what errors did you get?

Comment: Command raised an exception: InvalidDocument: cannot encode object: <Role id=850355452457779220 name='Подтвержден'>, of type: <class 'discord.role.Role'>
and when entering the second command:
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: KeyError: 'role'

Comment: @Den the first one speaks for itself, you can't put a `discord.Role` in MongoDB cause it doesn't know what to do with it. Store the ``ID`` of the role instead (second line of the `add_shop` command).

Comment: I would like to get the role ID, for adding a role using the command.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB and pymongo can only store objects of certain understood types, such as strings, numbers, dates and a few more that are listed [here](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/bson/index.html).

If you attempt to add in other types, objects, classes etc. outside these well defined types, you will get the error mentioned.

You will need to convert any types to the supported types; maybe try and convert to a string (using `str(object)`) if the class supports this, otherwise there's some useful general documentation here:

https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/custom_type.html

Comment: I was able to write the role to the database, but the output returns an error: discard. text.commands.errors.Command Invoke Error: Command raised an exception: KeyError: 'role'